# How do I use an array with a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <math.h> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Storage
{
public:
Storage();
string information[10][7];
void SetInformation(string,int);
void GetInformation(int);
};  

Storage::Storage(){cout<<"\nStorage Activated\n";}

void Storage::SetInformation(string,int i)
{//input
    i--;
    for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
    {
    switch(j+1)
    {case 1: cout << "\nFirst Name: "; break;
    case 2: cout << "\nLast Name: "; break;
    case 3: cout << "\nAge: "; break;
    case 4: cout << "\nEmail: "; break;
    case 5: cout << "\nDoor Number: "; break;
    case 6: cout << "\nRoad Name: "; break;
    case 7: cout << "\nPost Code: "; break;
    default:;}      
    cin >> information[i][j];}
    }

void Storage::GetInformation(int i){
// output
    i--;
    for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
    {   
    switch(j+1)
    {case 1: cout << "\nFirst Name: "; break;
    case 2: cout << "\nLast Name: "; break;
    case 3: cout << "\nAge: "; break;
    case 4: cout << "\nEmail: "; break;
    case 5: cout << "\nDoor Number: "; break;
    case 6: cout << "\nRoad Name: "; break;
    case 7: cout << "\nPost Code: "; break;
    default:;}      

    cout << information[i][j];}
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    Storage();
    Storage Someone;
    cin >> x;
    Someone.SetInformation(int);

return 0;
}
```

Ok this is what I have made now. But I am now having a problem activating the classes? and by that I mean that I cant use the class or its methods? Also have I created the classes in a correct way or not?

Answer (score 2):

Just have a class with the members `firstName`, `lastName`, etc. in it. Call it `Person` or whatever. Then replace your array with a `std::vector<Person>`.

Create member methods that read the specific information from the standard input (possibly an `enum` that tells the method which information to read).

Replace the `cout` at the end with a method that displays the information *per object*.

Comment: Or `Person * people = new Person[length];` if you can't use `std::vector`

Comment: @evanmcdonnal `Person people[10];` would be preferable.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, why would you not be able to use `std::vector`? If you can use the heap but can't use `std::vector` why bother using C++? There are other languages that might be more suitable than "crippled C++"

Comment: ^ this... If you can't use std::vector, why write C++? Why not C?

Comment: "Because some lame instructor in some unreal-world classroom says you can't use std::vector<> (or any of the other standard containers) but requires you to use C++." would be one reason. We've all seen it, time and time again. +1, btw.

Comment: @JonathanWakely that comment is from the perspective of someone who just completed a cs degree at a c++ school and you were not allowed to use `std` containers. A lot of the exercises at classes of this level were writing your own containers.

Comment: Fair enough, so it has a place, but I wouldn't suggest it to someone on SO unless they've specifically stipulated they can't use `vector`. Outside of an artificial classroom situation one should "put away childish things"

Comment: lol we cant use std::vector :))))) lame instructor, We have to make all the algorithms ourselves too.

Answer (score 0):

simple class and some methods just to get started:
This is more a "C" style than a C++, but is very simple to understand.
If you know more OOP rules that you can (and should) upgrade that

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person() { /*init with default values here if needed*/ isValid = false; }
    ~Person() { }

    /* add setters/getters if needed */
public:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int age;
    string email;
    int doorNumber;
    string roadName;
    string postCode;
    bool isValid;   // is the data valid
};
```

'methods':

```
void inputPersonData(Person &person)
{
    cout << "\nFirst Name: ";
    cin >> person.firstName;

    cout << "\nLast Name: ";
    cin >> person.lastName;

    cout << "\nAge: ";
    cin >> person.age;

    cout << "\nEmail: ";
    cin >> person.email;

    cout << "\nDoor Number: ";
    cin >> person.doorNumber;

    cout << "\nRoad Name: ";
    cin >> person.roadName;

    cout << "\nPost Code: ";
    cin >> person.postCode;

    person.isValid = true; // now the data is valid
}

void outputPersonData(Person &person)
{
    // do not print not loaded person data...
    if (person.isValid == false) return;

    // use cout to print...
}

// us it that way:
// deletePerson(information, 10, index_to_delete)
void deletePerson(Person *peopleArray, int count, int toDelete)
{
    peopleArray[toDelete].isValid = false;
}
```

simple search by name function, returns an index:

```
int searchPersonByName(Person *peopleArray, int count, const string &name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (peopleArray[i].firstName == name)
            return i;
    }
}
```

in main:

```
Person information[10];

// input
cout << "\nWhich Slot would you like to store the informaton in ?(1-10)";
cin >> i;
i--;
inputPersonData(information[i]);
outputPersonData(information[i]);
```

create a loop and in that loop ask a question to fill the data or search

Comment: public data members, free `inputPersonData` and `outputPersonData` instead of members, raw arrays... IMO this does more harm than good.

Comment: @fen if I created it your way would I be able to later use a search to find the data? eg by typing a name I could bring up all his details with an option to delete?(with a sort) Also what is the point of the Person information[10] array now? do I need array for this anymore?

Comment: @MRKHANCOMUTILeader as I understood you want to have 'database' for some people, so class Person represents single person and this array 'information[10]' represents the 'database'. First you fill the database and then you need to write methods for search and delete. I will update my above answer with those methods...

Answer (score 0):

You do not activate a class, you create an instance of it..

Here I am just pointing out some of your syntax error.. You should additionally follow the suggestions in the other answers above to create a more proper class definition for the person.

In you class,

```
void Storage::SetInformation(string,int i) <--- Wrong.
```

each parameter to the method needs to have a type followed by name, something like

```
void Storage::SetInformation(string name, int i)
```

Inside the methods, the way to format blocks is something similar to,

```
for ( ... ) {
    switch ( ... ) {

    }
}
```

this would make it more easier to read..

Inside your switch() statement,

If your intention is to get some values from the user, use "cin" statements after each of the prompts for "First Name", "Last Name", etc..

```
default:;}  <--- Error
```

change it to

```
    default: break;
}
```

In your main,

```
Storage();  <--- Delete this line
Storage Someone; <--- This is creating an instance of your class.
```

You will call a method on the instance of your class, but

```
Someone.SetInformation(int); <--- This is incorrect.
```

You need to pass a value to your method, not a type. "int" is a type specifier. 
Call the method as,

```
Someone.SetInformation("some text", x);
```

Comment: thank you very much helped a lot.   More questions coming soon :D